# How to obtain IP addresses of everything on network in c#

Tags: c#, networking, ip

I have a sonicwall on a network of around 100 machines.

I have tried and tried to find a way of creating 2 combobox's that will contain both the IP addresses linked to the sonicwall, as well as the currently logged in user of the machine as well.

What i am trying to create is a employee monitoring software (like Interguard/ActivTrak/etc), but am unable at present to even get near to finding this information?

I've been researching A LOT of stuff (~25 pages of google, with not a single link not clicked), and have met no conclusion as to get this information.

I'm not exactly a great programmer, but I would LOVE to be able to get this sort of information into two combobox's/arrays/other suitable object/control.

If anyone knows a way of even creating an array of IP addresses, along with corresponding Logins, that would be of great help to this project!

(PLEASE NOTE: I know there is a Networking exchange site, but I have already looked! Also, since i'm designing a piece of software for this, I thought i'd ask it here!)

Thanks for any advice/suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is similar to a packet sniffer application like wireshark or ethereal. But if you want to design it yourself, I think your best solution is a collection/list to store the data that is binded to a datagrid.

Comment: it would have elements yes, but even wireshark has its limitations!

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an Active Directory domain, you could use the code from [my S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727997/c-sharp-get-ip-of-remote-computer-on-separate-dns-server/25770013#25770013). Instead of using the CheckConnectionAsync() method to check for connectivity, you could just re-write it to get the IP address using System.Net.Dns.

To retrieve the user, you can use WMI. For this, you need to make a reference to the System.Management namespace.

```
public Task<string> GetUserName(string ComputerName)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ConnectionOptions conn = ConnectionOptions()
        {
            EnablePrivileges = true,
            Username = // string in format of @"DomainName\UserName",
            Password = password,
            Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
            Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
        };

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + ComputerName + @"\root\cimv2", conn);

        try
        {
            scope.Connect();
            ObjectQuery user = new ObjectQuery("Select UserName From Win32_ComputerSystem");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, user);
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject m in collection)
            {
                string username = m["UserName"].ToString().Trim();
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                {
                    return username;
                }
            }

            return null; // no current logged in user
        }
        catch (Exception) // error handling...
    });
}
```

Then, just iterate through your collection of computers and retrieve the username like so:

```
private async Task RetrieveUsers()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Computers, c =>
    {
        string user = await GetUserName(c.Name); // or c.IP. both work.
    });
}
```

Comment: would this not have serious security issues though?

Comment: You would need to have an account with admin credentials to perform these methods. It would be the same as trying to access AD without an account with permissions to anything in AD. So not really any security issues. It just all depends on how you provide the authentication information to the methods.

Comment: it's quite easy to 'hack' most computers these days to get an admin account - plus what happens if another user has admin privaledges?

Comment: Well, if you want to be able to get the current logged in user for remote machines and enumerate the computers that reside in AD, this is the way to do it, which requires admin credentials. So you would have to put a mechanism in place to authenticate someone using your application (i.e.- prompting for the authentication information within the application vs. storing it in code) and limit the footprint of the application's availability on your network. All things you have to consider when doing anything related to managing a network.